# Correct type definition for a variable assigned with an enum

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm wondering what is the correct type definition for a variable assigned with an enum inside an Angular's component.

Consider this situation:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard-component',
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent {
    componentActions = ComponentActions;

    ...
}

export enum ComponentActions {
    ACTION_OK,
    ACTION_CANCEL,
}
```

Basically, I need to use `ComponentActions` enum inside my component's template, so I assigned the `componentActions` public variable with the `ComponentActions` enum, and I want to **specify the type of this public variable**.

The following code:

```js
componentActions: ComponentActions = ComponentActions;
```

will throws an error in `tslint`:

`Type 'typeof ComponentActions' is not assignable to type 'ComponentActions'`

Otherwise, using the following code:

```js
componentActions: typeof ComponentActions = ComponentActions;
```

there is no error from `tslint`.

My question is: what is the correct type for the public variable? It's sufficient to use `typeof` keyword or there is a specific way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm going to answer my own question.

Accordingly to typescript's definition, in the below code:

```js
componentActions: typeof ComponentActions = ComponentActions;
```

the `typeof` is called **type query**.

A type query obtains the type of an identifier or property access expression and it's the most close to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1):

You should not assign enum to the variable. Enum is just an object. You need to pass the type and assign one of the enums values.

```
componentActions: ComponentActions = ComponentActions.ACTION_OK;
```

Comment: This way I cannot access the enum values inside my component's template, because `componentActions` now is a simple value and not the entire enum object

Comment: `componentActions = {...ComponentActions};`

Comment: Or if you need it as an array `Object.keys(ComponentActions)`

Comment: `componentActions = ComponentActions;` just works fine, my problem is specify the type for `componentActions`

Comment: `interface IComponentActions {
  [key: string]: ComponentActions;
}`

Answer (score 0):

*Type 'typeof ComponentActions' is not assignable to type 'ComponentActions'*

The error states that you tried to assign a type to a variable of a type - of course this is not possible. To assign a value to the enum variable:

```
componentActiosn: ComponentActions = ComponantActions.ONE_OF_YOUR_DEFINED_ENUM VALUES; (ACTION_OK, ACTION_CANCEL)
```

Comment: As I said in the other answer, this way I cannot access the enum values inside my component's template, because componentActions now is a simple value and not the entire enum object